# Powershell: FileSystemWatcher filter option - Not working.

Tags: powershell, filter

I would like to watch out for files having name like  "today's date then 6digits then _ABC_XYZ.csv". For e.g. if today's date is 20181011 then the file should be the name: 20181011123456_ABC_XYZ.csv. Below is my code:

```
$DateStr = $Date.ToString("yyyyMMdd")

### SET FOLDER TO WATCH + FILES TO WATCH + SUBFOLDERS YES/NO
    $watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
    $watcher.Path = "E:\\Sid\\source"
    $watcher.Filter = $DateStr + "\d\d\d\d\d\d*_Recon_ForeignExchange.csv"
    $watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true
    $watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true  

### DEFINE ACTIONS AFTER AN EVENT IS DETECTED
    $action = { $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
                $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
                $logline = "$(Get-Date), $changeType, $path"
                Add-content "D:\log.txt" -value $logline            
              }    
### DECIDE WHICH EVENTS SHOULD BE WATCHED 
    Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action $action
    Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Changed" -Action $action
    Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Deleted" -Action $action
    Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Renamed" -Action $action
    while ($true) {sleep 5}
```

My Queries:

1. Its seems that the $watcher.filter is not working as it's taking files other than the one given in the filter as well.
2. Also I would like to watch 2 folders at a time as the file can come in any of the folders. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Are you sure that your Regex works properly? For a second folder, you need a second watcher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Theo pointed out, the [Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher.filter?view=netframework-4.7.2) property does not support regex. Only path wildcards are allowed.

You will have to use a simpler wildcard in your filter:

```
# rough wildcard filter
$watcher.Filter = "*_Recon_ForeignExchange.csv"
```

..and then perform a more specific (regex) check in your handler:

```
$action = {   
  $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
  # check if the file name has the desired format
  if ((Split-Path $path -Leaf) -match ($DateStr + "\d\d\d\d\d\d*_Recon_ForeignExchange.csv"))
    $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
    $logline = "$(Get-Date), $changeType, $path"
    Add-content "D:\log.txt" -value $logline
  }    
}
```

As for the other directory, @vrdse already pointed out that you're going to need a 2nd watcher for that.

Comment: I think the asteriks should not be in the regex. With this, you will also match `201810111234567890147852369454878951651981651_Recon_ForeignExchange.csv`, but the op states it should match at **"today's date then 6digits**. I would suggest using `"$DateStr\d{6}_Recon_ForeignExchange.csv"` or more generic: `"$DateStr20181011\d{6}_\w+_\w+.csv"`

Comment: @Theo Thanks your pattern will work I suppose. I left the regex unchanged. The question was primarily about the use of the FileWatcher class. Also it could be by design that more than 6 digits will be supported in the future.

Comment: "$DateStr\d{6}_Recon_ForeignExchange.csv" and "$DateStr20181011\d{6}_\w+_\w+.csv" are very useful. Thanks for the same.